# Trying to use Generic Factory with an action in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, generics, action

I'm building an mvc 4 application that has a search page.  The search action takes two values from the view passed through the query string.  One of the values is the selected value from a ddllist.  Currently, I'm matching that value with an enum using an if else statement.  Depending on what the value is I'm instantiating an object that uses entity to query my db.  I then return an Ienumrable list of some object back to my controller and generate a webgrid.

For example,

```
public actionresult searchforborrower(string searchTerm)
{
   if(searchTerm == enum.queryborrowername)
     var result = ctx.getborrowername();
   else if (searchTerm == enum.queryguarantorname)
     var result = ctx.getguarantorname();

return view(result);
}
```

I'm looking for a better way to handle instantiating the search query especially since this is a hassle to maintain.  Have looked at generic factory and command pattern.  They don't seem to be best solutions because I'm returning an enumerated list of some type.

Comment: use case instead if and i didn't see any problem with that code.